# Capturing stdout in real time in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, command-line-interface

I'm firing off cap tasks and other command line scripts from a function but I'm wondering what the best way for me to display real time logs for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up with the solution in this snippet

```
STDOUT.sync = true
IO.popen(command+" 2>&1") do |pipe|
  pipe.sync = true
  while str = pipe.gets
    puts "-> "+str
  end
end
```